# QR Code command to send multiple sms c#

Tags: c#, winforms, sms, qr-code

I am using QR code to send sms over phone and process for that is:

- My computer application generates QR code with text of `SMSTO:+381123456789, +381123456789, +381123456789:MessageText`
- I scan this QR code with QR Code Reader [LINK](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tw.mobileapp.qrcode.banner&hl=en_US)
- Inside it i press `Send message` and it open message application on my phone, insert numbers and text

So this process works great but there is problem when there are more than 20 numbers.

So phone can send one message to maximum of 20 numbers and if i have let's say 36 numbers it will delete last 16 numbers when creating message in sms application.

To escalate this i want to write QR Code which will create 2 separate messages with 20 and 16 numbers. So i have `SMSTO:+381123456789, +381123456789, +381123456789:MessageText` to send one message but how would it look if i want 2 messages and if that is possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is the device or/and Carrier specific problem
[See This](https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1847759) [And This](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7502173)